# How to convert hexadecimal NSData into decimal NSData?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to convert long hexadecimal number`371d2a3f041fb4ab210fe7567b3a041f9072089790f9b34139fb2df7301ebcad`
into long decimal number `24928736809215721890296636138640601514085104766215587836409400141363575438509` in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a type that can store an arbitrary-sized integer. There is no native type for this in Foundation, but a Google search for "bigint in objective-c" should give you some ideas.